# How to do DNS lookup of an ip range using shell script

Tags: shell, reverse-dns

How to do DNS lookup of an IP range using shell script

when I do dig -x and provide an ip i get reverser DNS for the respective ip. However if I give range either CIDRs or ip range from & to thats a long manual process, which I want to get it working using shell script.

I tried

```
dig -x 1x.xx.xx.xx

;; ANSWER SECTION:

1x.xx.xx.xx.foo.addr. port IN   PTR
```

I want to see reverse DNS of all ips falling in that range when I pass either 
1x.xx.xx.xx/24
or 
1x.xx.xx.xx - 1x.xx.xx.xxx

Comment: Sorry, but S.O. isn't a free coding service. You're expected to research the problem, post your best attempt at solving the problem, including sample inputs and expected outputs. Please read [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. One hint, do you know about `grep` or `awk` ? maybe `dig -x ... | grep 'stuff  you want to find'` can get you started. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I got it, I was just expecting any way which could be give me an output of CIDR range. I understood when you say about grep or awk but the question was instead of looking for 1 ip each time, can I get output for all ips falling in the CIDR range?

I got the way to do it by using nmap 
```nmap -sL 4x.xx.xx.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report/{print $NF}' | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo "%: $(dig -x % +short)"'```

Answer (score 1):

I got the way to do this. 
using nmap we can achieve this.

`nmap -sL 4x.xx.xx.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report/{print $NF}' | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo "%: $(dig -x % +short)"'`

output

```
41.74.205.0:
4x.xx.xx.1:a2b-foo.c.
4x.xx.xx.2:a2b-foo.c.
4x.xx.xx.3:
4x.xx.xx.4:
4x.xx.xx.5:
4x.xx.xx.6:
41.74.205.7:foo-smtp-delivery-foo.com.
41.74.205.8:foo-smtp-delivery-foo.com.
41.74.205.9:foo-smtp-delivery-foo.com.
41.74.205.10:foo-smtp-delivery-foo.com.
```

I was expecting this way. I can now create a shell script and ask for an input range and show this sort of output.